# How to configure spring filters for only paths configured by controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project and a spring rest project. In both cases, I'm using a filter to add a session ID for SLF4J/Logback logging. However, the filter is getting called for every HTTP request like static files, favicon.ico etc. I know this is happening because I'm using /* in filters. How to prevent this ? I want filter to be called for only for paths handled by my controllers. Here is my filter set in web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>AppRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.company.appui.filter.AppRequestFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AppRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

another app where I'm configuring filter in java program

```
private void registerFilters(Environment environment, ApplicationContext context) { 
    environment.addFilter(context.getBean(AppRequestFilter.class), "/*"); 
    environment.addFilter(context.getBean(AuthFilter.class), "/*"); 
}
```

Sample URL for my spring rest project

```
localhost:8080/v1/apphealthcheck/epp?token=37e11b48119d
```

Sample URL for spring MVC project

`localhost:28082/app-ui/index.html` - home page
`localhost:28082/app-ui/login` - for ajax call from index.html

Comment: can you post your url-patterns for spring mvc and spring rest projects ?

Comment: So is it safe to assume that all mvc URLs will have `app-ui` and all rest calls will have `v1` ??

Comment: @Arkantos, my production URL for mvc will be mydomain.com/index.html or mydomain.com/login for ajax calls. For rest it will be mydomain.com/v1/healthcheck. So rest calls will have v1. MVC won't have app-ui

Comment: Ok does your static files have something in common ? Something like `static` in  `//your-domain/static/js/app.js`

Comment: @Arkantos, No. I think I did a blunder in that case. I can move them to static if that brings me any performance advantage of not calling filter. Also, all dynamic content urls for now are domain.com/<resource> - there no additional slashes. If it is domain.com/pathto/something - we can assume this is a static in case of spring mvc project .For rest, I don't have any static files at all except for this favicon.ico coming up in my requests. I don't have a file for it on my server. May be I should setup a controller for it and return empty body ?

Comment: If all your static files have `static` prefix in path, then we can try and exclude them but we don't have any direct option to do that.You have to manually check for those excluded patterns in doFilter() method and handle it accordingly. But instead of changing path for static files, you can try adding a prefix for your mvc URLs something like `your-domain/app/login` and `your-domain/app/home`. Assuming your application is relatively new, at least code changes will be minimum :)

Comment: Can you show me as how you are adding the sessionId and using it for loggerin your filter?

Comment: Then we can configure filters only for those patterns like `<url-pattern>/app/*, /v1/healthcheck/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: @minion, it is logback MDC logging. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Arkantos changing controller URL. to have prefix seems to be a good idea than moving all static files. I only have couple of URL resources at this time. So that is easy. For rest also, all resources are at /v1/* - this also  sounds to be good idea. I will try that  and post here.

Comment: Well, ControllerAdvice can intercept your only your controller requests. But I don't know if it can help in your case. My question is based on that thought. Take a look at @controllerAdvice annotation. But it is always good to split and serve static resources.

Comment: @minion, I'm under impression that ControllerAdvice is good for exception handling only ?

Comment: Well, you can have model attributes that is common to all controllers etc. This may be a hack depending on situation. If you could differentiate with url patterns, thats the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify comma separated values in `url-pattern` or even use multiple `url-pattern elements in`filter-mapping`. But for that to work, you need to have common prefix in your MVC controller URLs and REST URLs.

Now you can have the following mappings in web.xml

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*,/v1/healthcheck/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

or

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/v1/healthcheck/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: thanks. This helped. Now because of the path change, I'm trying to work around my cookies. My /api/something API call sets cookies and they seems to be not accessible for JS running at / . Looks like different question, but please throw pointers if you have any.

Comment: I could simply set path when creating cookie in Java program. Never mind. Thanks.

Comment: But cookies are at domain level, as long as your domain same for all dynamic content, you should be able to access them

Answer (score 1):

You could've solved this by adding a specific URL path branch for all controller handled requests at the beginning and mapping the filter to that URL.
Is it too late to refactor? Restful services are usually flexible this way while in development...